# Не выводятся данные из бд в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть шаблон с разметкой /layouts/main, который я вывожу на всех страницах через @extends. Так же есть список вопросов из БД в этом же шаблоне(нужно, чтобы он был тоже на всех страницах). Но сейчас переходя на страницы, выдает ошибку $faq is undefined. А если перейти напрямую на main.blade с разметкой, то вопросы есть. Как исправить ситуацию?

```html
<!-- FAQ -->
<section id="faq" class="my-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <h2 class="h2-m">Важные вопросы и ответы на них</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper my-5">
      <div class="faq-tabs">
        @foreach($faq as $el)
        <div class="tab">
          <input id="tab-{{ $el->id }}" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-{{ $el->id }}">{{ $el->title }}</label>
          <div class="tab-content">
            {!! $el->text !!}
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- FAQ end-->
```

Строю маршрут:

```html
Route::get('/layouts/main', [ FaqController::class, 'faq' ])->name('faq');
```

Контроллер:

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FaqController extends Controller
{
  public function faq()
  {
    $faq = DB::table('faq')->get();

    return view('/layouts/main', ['faq' => $faq]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно сказать в чем причина ошибки, не погружаясь в ваше приложение, но как вариант решения проблемы объявить и передать во все представления объект $faq в провайдере AppServiceProvider. Насколько я понял, вам нужно выводить список faq на всех страницах сайта. Вам подойдет такой код:

```
 $faq = DB::table('faq')->get();
 view()->share(['faq ' => $faq]);
```